# Batch download webpages as displayed by browser

Tags: wget, browser-addons, web

Wget doesn't work because the page is dynamic, and no matter what options I put it won't download some of the text shown in Firefox.

I Googled quite a bit, but all the solutions I find are quite cumbersome, like writing a script that sends firefox specific key strokes.  However some of the answers are old, so I wonder if something better exists now.

All I need from the pages is text, I don't need any images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if something better exists now.

Based on personal experience, I would venture to say it seems unlikely to me.

For pages with content rendered by JavaScript only when visible (which is what it sounds like you're describing), the best solution I have come across is [Python](https://www.python.org/), running [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) (available via `pip`/[PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)) controlling e.g. [Ungoogled Chromium](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium) (Windows builds available [here](https://woolyss.com/)).

And this still requires (at least some) scripting for Python/Selenium to control e.g. Ungoogled Chromium.

Also note that in the case of JavaScript rendered only when visible, you probably will have to [execute some JavaScript via Selenium to scroll the web page](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html#how-to-scroll-down-to-the-bottom-of-a-page). It's also worth noting that JavaScript elements may not be rendered under a modern browser (Chrome/Firefox) running in "headless" mode (i.e. without a GUI). So you may have to watch your web browser browse those pages, unfortunately.

---

*I would also suggest potentially looking into [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) with [lxml](https://lxml.de/) as well for parsing HTML (available via `pip`/PyPI [here](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) and [here](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/)). You can get web page text via Selenium, but in some cases, saving the page for parsing later may be simpler.*